Is it Haram for me to write smut if I am only writing them for myself and am not sharing them?
Is it haram to write scenes where two characters who are married have sex as long as I am writing them for my own and I am not sharing them with anyone else? And if it’s wrong is it morally wrong or straight up haram?
